# How to redirect springboot error page to vaadin error UI?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin8

I have an error page in vaadin UI. But sometimes we can write a wrong url and we see the springboot error page.

I want to show vaadin UI error page in this case. By the way, I have already have a rendered 404 page for springboot. But I don't want to show it.

This is my vaadin error UI. But this works into the application. (http://localhost:7001/MyApplication/#!error)

sometimes I write an invalid url like this: http://localhost:7001/MyApplication/blablablabla

in this case I want to redirect vaadin error page (http://localhost:7001/MyApplication/#!error) But the springboot redirects me to rendered 404 page.

It is possible?

```
@UIScope
@SpringView(name = ErrorView.VIEW_NAME)
public class ErrorView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "error";

    private Label explanation;

    public ErrorView() {
        Label header = new Label("The view could not be found");
        header.addStyleName(MaterialTheme.LABEL_H1);
        addComponent(header);
        addComponent(explanation = new Label());
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        explanation.setValue(String.format("You tried to navigate to a view ('%s') that does not exist.", event.getViewName()));
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(ErrorView.VIEW_NAME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put 404/500 page under resources/error/  folder, Spring boot will redirect those page automatic when have error

Comment: Sorry, but vaadin UI not an html page. I know your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think SpringNavigator can solve your problem. While defining your Navigator, you can also define error View. See the example below

```
@SpringUI(path = "ui")
public class DemoUI extends com.vaadin.ui.UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        SpringNavigator navigator = new SpringNavigator();
        navigator.setErrorView(new ErrorView());
        setNavigator(navigator);
    }
}
```

Comment: navigator object is null when we use different url out the vaadin path

Comment: Thats because this a type of com.vaadin.navigator which is designed to navigate through vaadin pages.